# apache mod_isapi public exploits

Tags: exploit, known-vulnerabilities

In public apache mod_isapi exploits, they ask for dlls, and I am unsure what I should put in dll.

I am having a hard time understanding exploits.. How does all of dlls connect to manipulating isapi.dll?

Comment: *"In public apache mod_isapi exploits"* - Do you have a reference?

Comment: http://www.metasploit.com/modules/auxiliary/dos/http/apache_mod_isapi

Comment: If you're asking about how to use a particular Metasploit module, and if the public documentation is not sufficient, I would suggest that you [buy a support license from Metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com/help/) or [ask on the Metasploit forums](https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit?view=discussions).  Your question is very naarrow and you're probably more likely to get a good response there.

Comment: kindly go on exploit-db or exploitsdownload or 1337day site to find exploits for the same.

Answer (score 1):

By default, metasploit requests `/cgi-bin/SMTPSend.dll`

The idea is that the DLL is forced to be unloaded by the server then requested again by the attacker, resulting in a potential violation of the memory pointer because mod_isapi doesn't properly cleanup the pointers to an unloaded DLL.